# How to get liveserver to render django templates?

Tags: css, django, visual-studio-code, server, django-templates

I've been messing around with a tutorial site, and I found that my VS Code LiveServer plugin doesn't work properly when I try to open Django templates. The CSS I applied is missing (**although everything renders correctly in my local development sever**), and the template language code is actually printed to the screen rather than executed (see image below). My liveserver plugin appears to be working with html files outside of Django.

(1) Right now I'm right clicking and selecting "Open with Liveserver." Is this wrong for Django? The liveserver docs recommend trying to "visit the Actual Server Address: http://localhost/[workspace], not the VS Code extension's Live Server Address: [http://127.0.0.1:5500/"](http://127.0.0.1:5500/%22). I tried including the file path in place of [workspace], but no luck. What do I do here?

(2) I saw in another thread where someone recommended their own solution, [here](https://livereload.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I'm not sure where I'm supposed to run the './manage.py livereload' command, but it's not working in command prompt. What is the difference between './manage.py' and 'py manage.py'? And will this solution be any better than the VS Code plugin?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have had the same problem as you and managed to get it working with the link you included in point (2) of your post. You may have gotten sorted by now, but I thought I'd post it here in case.

First I went to my console and ran:

```
pip install livereload
```

which was installed successfully. Then I added `'livereload'` to my installed apps in my settings.py file. E.g...

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        ...
    'livereload',
        ...
    ]
```

Then I went to the directory containing my manage.py file on the terminal and ran

```
./manage.py livereload
```

and this provided me with a link to a live update server. Previously I had been running a server with "python manage.py runserver", so this is to replace that command.
Now when I save any changes I make in my IDE, they update live on the browser.
Sorry that I haven't included any screenshot images for clarity, I wasn't able to for some reason.

Comment: for me it does not get the static files i get 404

Comment: @alirezaeasazade did you find a solution to this? Getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I am working through Scrimba/VSchool tutorial, so I am wondering if you may have run into this problem through a similar path.
I believe Live Server and Django are incompatible - but if you find a fix, let me know.

Live server is acting as your web server (port 5500 by default), serving up files as your make changes.
Django is also acting as a web server (port 8000 by default), interpreting Python code, and rendering the Django Template Language.

Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, live server cannot execute all this Python code, so all the Django Template Language will not render.  This includes the {% load static %} method that Django uses to read the CSS & JS links in the html.

Comment: I eventually came to the same conclusion, but will keep my eyes open for a fix. It seems like there are some workarounds for PHP based frameworks, but not yet Django.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who tried the top answer, but still got stuck: you have to install dj-static, or whitenoise (as recommended by the dj-static github page) to serve the static files. I noticed that it's really slow though. Maybe it's just me, but I found it to be quite unworkable. I ended up writing an autohotkey script to activate my browser and then refresh. At least for me, that´s a lot quicker.

Answer (score -3):

in your command line you have to run the server by the following command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

but be sure that you are in the directory that has manage.py file. you don't need to type the port. because you will get the default port which is:8000

Comment: My development server has been running the whole time. It loads the templates without issues. Any other ideas?

Comment: you have no mind to run the code over..
above you didn't run the server in that case you ran the browser as you do in the static HTML and CSS files and that isn't work in a case of Python so, you need to run the server

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having a hard time understanding you, but again, I did run the server. I already used the command "python manage.py runserver". That is not the solution to my problem.

Comment: which port do you run? the default port is working with port :8000 so, if you run the server by the command that I have sent you to have to run write the next URL in URL field: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 
to see the page

Comment: Yes I have already run the url at  127.0.0.1:8000 after using the command that you sent me. That webpage works fine, I have been using it for months, but it won't livereload.

Comment: you can do that by the following command: python manage.py runserver localhost:5500

Comment: Ok, the server is running at localhost:5500 but it still won't live reload. I'll keep experimenting with things.