# Why is CSS not updating with live reload in django

Tags: python, css, django, livereload

I just figured out how to use live reload with django - ([How to get liveserver to render django templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62667561/how-to-get-liveserver-to-render-django-templates)). I used the first answer (but instead of `./manage.py livereload`, I did `python manage.py livereload`.

My problem is that now the CSS is not uploading. I know it is because of the live reload because when I use the regular `python manage.py runserver`, the CSS loads.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

(When in my command prompt (I use Windows 10), and while in the directory which contains the `manage.py` file, I type `./manage.py livereload`.)

Comment: To reload CSS files, which are just static files you have to perform `python manage.py collectstatic`...

Comment: raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://livereload.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) of livereload they say _To automagically serve static files like the native runserver command you have to use dj-static. (follow the simple instructions there)._ but dj-static is not maintained and recommends [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) instead, try using it, it may solve your problem.

Comment: 'To enable WhiteNoise you need to wrap your existing WSGI application in a WhiteNoise instance and tell it where to find your static files.' - do I do this is my wsgi.py in my app? Thank you

Comment: @TheProCoder no see that it says "QuickStart for _other_ WSGI apps" (other than Django) See the next page of the documentation to avoid any confustion: [Using WhiteNoise with Django](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html)

Comment: Thank you @Abdul Aziz Barkat. I was just reading over this question again, and noticed that I forgot to thank you.